# Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file react native

Tags: android, react-native, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am building a project and integrating jitsi meet on it.
while running `npx react-native run-android`

this is what I am getting in my terminal -

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file

```
'/Users/sheshnarayandeshmukh/Desktop/react-native-jitsi-meet/ExampleApp/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/sheshnarayandeshmukh/.gradle/caches/6.7.1/scripts/99fmkpl7ogm1borct3vt887my).
```

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 61

Configurations :
java version - 17.0.3
gradle version - 6.7.1
OS - Mac

thanks in advance for help